Does this correspond to a specific family of directed graphs?
I'm interested in directed graphs that

admit a book embedding of two pages, i.e. an ordering of the vertices on a line and each arc embedded in one of the two half-planes without edges crossing,

AND

the book embedding has all arcs on page 1 go in one direction (suppose the increasing direction: from a lower vertex to a higher vertex in the ordering) and all arcs on page 2 go in the other direction (suppose the decreasing direction).

An example of such a directed graph is given in the figure below. Any directed cycle can be ordered on the line (dashed in the figure) according to the order of the vertices in the cycle, and all arcs go in page 1 except for the final arc linking the last vertex to the first, which is embedded on page 2. Some edges such as shown in red and dotted in the figure can be added without issue: the resulting directed graph can still be embedded in this particular manner.

Does this family correspond to a specific known family of directed graphs? By relating to known results on book embeddings for undirected graphs, it must include all directed graphs which are outerplanar when directions are removed (since one can simply put all arcs on one page without crossing and then move the decreasing direction arcs to the second page), and it must be included in the family of directed graphs that are subhamiltonian when directions are removed.

The direction property is a bit confusing… What does increasing order mean? Is it about vertices numbering? In that case, why would decreasing order matter compared to increasing, since you could renumber vertices on page 2? Overall, an example of such a graph would be most welcome.

@Nathaniel I added some clarification, with an example and a figure.
